# Simplying an ODE expression.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, trigonometry

I am having trouble trying to understand how this simplification of one of the coupled ODEs was obtained. The first ODE is:
$$
(m_1 r_1 - m_2 r - m_3 r_2)g \sin{\theta_1} = (m_1 r_1^2 + I_{zz} + m_3 r_2^2) \ddot{\theta_1} + m_3 r_2 r_3[\ddot{\theta_2} \cos{(\theta_1 - \theta_2)} + \dot{\theta_2}^2 \sin{(\theta_1 - \theta_2)}] 
$$

The other set of the ODE is:

$$
-g \sin{\theta_2} = r_3 \ddot{\theta_2} + r_2[\ddot{\theta_1} \cos{(\theta_1 - \theta_2)} - \dot{\theta_1}^2 \sin{(\theta_1 - \theta_2)}]
$$

In my attempt to simplify it, the furthest I got was making $\ddot{\theta_1} $ the subject of the formula, and I did not think that it needed more simplifying. When I looked at the solution, I could not understand how that answer was achieved. It is also said that $1 - \cos^2{x} = \sin^2{x} $ was used to obtain this simplification. The simplification is below. Solution:

$$
\ddot{\theta_1} = \frac{g \sin{\theta_1} (m_1 r_1 - m_2 r - m_3 r_2) + m_3 r_2 [g \sin{\theta_2} \cos{(\theta_1 - \theta_2)} - r_3 \dot{\theta_2}^2 \sin{(\theta_1 - \theta_2)} - r_2 \dot{\theta_1}^2 \cos{(\theta_1 - \theta_2)} \sin{(\theta_1 - \theta_2)}]}{m_1 r_1^2 + I_{zz} + m_2 r_2^2 \sin^2{(\theta_1 - \theta_2)}}
$$

Whereas the second ODE equation stays the same and $\ddot{\theta_2}$ is the subject of the formual

If anyone can help me and explain how that was obtained, I would be very grateful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you please give more explainary on the variable? for example, is $r$ a vector or a scalar? Thanks.

Comment: r amd m are scalar, they represent mass and length

Comment: As I said in your SO question, there should be a second equation so that you get a linear system for the second derivatives. The last formula you get is a result of solving this linear system via inverse matrix or Cramer formula.

Comment: ohh ok, I'll add that equation just now

Comment: I just editted in the second equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a linear system
$$
\pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}}
\pmatrix{\ddot\theta_1\\\ddot\theta_2}
=
\pmatrix{b_1\\b_2}
$$
with
\begin{align}
a_{11}&=(m_1 r_1^2 + I_{zz} + m_3 r_2^2)\\
a_{12}&=m_3 r_2 r_3\cos{(\theta_1 - \theta_2)}\\
b_1&=(m_1 r_1 - m_2 r - m_3 r_2)g \sin{\theta_1} -  m_3 r_2 r_3   \sin{(\theta_1 - \theta_2)}\,\dot\theta_2^2
\\[.5em]
a_{21}&=r_2\cos{(\theta_1 - \theta_2)}\\
a_{22}&=r_3\\
b_2&=-g \sin{\theta_2} + r_2 \sin{(\theta_1 - \theta_2)} \,\dot{\theta_1}^2
\end{align}

Applying the transpose of the cofactor matrix gives
$$
(a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21})\pmatrix{\ddot\theta_1\\\ddot\theta_2}
=
\pmatrix{a_{22}&-a_{12}\\-a_{21}&a_{11}}
\pmatrix{b_1\\b_2}
$$
which you can expand to get the explicit solution expressions, or you can take this as procedure to compute the solution using shorter expressions.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, this is so much more understandable. I also tried using the Cramer formula and that also helped me understand.